# Save the Image of activity on click of menu item

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I have and activity where on click of menu item save I want to save the image of the screen to my device inside a a specific folder. how can I do it. ?

The image which is displayed in the background is a ImageView and the text is textview. I have to merge them and save them as a single image.

[image]

Comment: what do u mean by merging?? and pls share the code where u tried doing it

Comment: I Mean to say is what ever is seen on the screen that is the image and the text, I want to store it as an image on the device

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code on menu item click event....

```
View v = view.getRootView();
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = v.getDrawingCache();

// give path of external directory to save image
String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myPath = new File(extr, "test.jpg");
FileOutputStream fos = null;

try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();       
} catch (Exception e) {       
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

where view v is root layout...

Comment: Permission to be added ?

Comment: Yes...you need to add this permission `<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
/>`

Comment: It take the picture of action bar as well I dont want the action bar in the picture. How can i remove that.

Comment: take your parent view instead of root view... by findViewById(R.id.yourView);

Comment: You mean to say the ImageView on which am putting the textview. Sorry but am new to android.

Comment: Your xml's parent view like RelativeLayout or LinearLayout in which ImageView & TextView are located.

Comment: I have taken RelativeLayout and I have used that only for the code you have given. relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drag_activity_layout);
View v = relativeLayout.getRootView();

Comment: Instead of `View v = relativeLayout.getRootView();`... try with `View v =  findViewById(R.id.drag_activity_layout);`

Comment: Please accept my answer if it's worked for you...& my name is Priyank, not Priyanka... :P :)